# How can I define a abstract odd function in mathematica?

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica

How can I define a abstract odd function, say f[x].

Whenever f[x]+f[-x] appears, mathematica simplifies it to zero.

Comment: There are several function atrributes in m@, such as `Orderless`. What I want is a "OddFunction" atrribute, is there a way to do this? thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done easily using upvalues

```
f[x_] + f[y_] /; x == -y ^:= 0
```

Normally Mathematica would try to assign the above rule to `Plus`, which of course does not work since that's protected. By using `^:=` instead of `:=` you can assign the rule to `f`. A quick check yields:

```
In[2]:=   f[3]+f[-3]
Out[2]:=  0
```

Edit: This, however, only works for `Plus`. It's probably better to use something more general, like:

```
f[x_?Negative] := -f[-x]
```

Now this also works with things like

```
In[4]:=  -f[3] - f[-3]
Out[4]:= 0
```

If you also want the function to work symbolically, you could add something like:

```
f[-a_] := -f[a]
```

Comment: Totally shocked by your answer. Thanks, einbandi. Really, Really what I want.

Comment: Yes, combination of `f[x_?Negative] := -f[-x]` for numbers and `f[-a_] := -f[a]` for symbols is also a excellent alternative. Thanks, einbandi.

Answer (score 1):

I am not good at this, but how about using the `TransformationFunctions` of `Simplify` ?

For example, suppose you have the expression `2 Sin[x] + f[x] + 3 + f[-x] + g[x] + g[-x]` and you want to simplify it, assuming `f[x]` is odd function and `g[x]` is even. Then we want a rule to say `f[x]+f[-x]->0` and a rule `g[x]+g[-x]->2 g[x]`.

Hence write

```
myRules[e_]:=e/.f[x]+f[-x]->0/.g[x]+g[-x]->2 g[x]

Simplify[2 Sin[x]+ f[x]+ 3 +f[-x]+ g[x] + g[-x],
         TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,myRules}]
```

and this gives

```
3+2 g[x]+2 Sin[x]
```

Btw, in the above, I am using `f[x]` where it really should be a pattern `f[x_]`, so that expression such as `f[anything]+f[-anything]` will also become zero. So, this needs to be improved to make `myRules` more general. Now it only works for the exact expression `f[x]`. I am not sure now how to improve this. Might need a delayed rule or so. Will think about it more. But you get the idea I hope.