# How can I define an abstract odd function in mathematica? With respect to derivatives

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want "to work symbolically" but not only with function but with derivatives. For instance I would like

```
f'[x] - f'[-x]
```

to be simplified to zero.

*Comment*: Neither of the ways, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342237/how-can-i-define-a-abstract-odd-function-in-mathematica), did not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They kind of works but now you need to create rules for `Derivative` not to `f` really. And since `Derivative` is not even protected you can do something like:

```
Derivative[n_][f][-x_] := -Derivative[n][f][x]

f''[x] + f'''''''[-x] + f''[-x] + f[x] + f'''''''[x]
```

> ```
> f[x]
> ```

is this ok?

Comment: @quinque by all you mean all degrees?